# Terraform dynamic block module

Tags: terraform, processor, datadog

I am trying to create dynamic block for the below datadog custom pipeline however I can see only verbose category but not Debug category, is there any way to get both debug & Verbose.

**Resource:**

```
dynamic "processor" {
    for_each = var.processor
    content {
        dynamic "category_processor" {
        for_each = length(keys(lookup(processor.value, "category_processor", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup(processor.value, "category_processor", {})]
        content {
            target = category_processor.value["target"]
            name = lookup(category_processor.value, "name", null)
            is_enabled = lookup(category_processor.value, "is_enabled", null)
            dynamic "category" {
                for_each = length(keys(lookup(category_processor.value, "category", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup( category_processor.value, "category", {})]
                content {
                name = category.value.name
                    dynamic "filter" {
                    for_each = length(keys(lookup(category.value, "filter", {}))) == 0 ? [] : [lookup( category.value, "filter", {})]
                    content{
                        query=filter.value.query
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
    }
 }
}
```

**Variable:**

```
variable "processor" {
    description = "One or more processors (multiples allowed)."
    type = any
    default = {
        processor {
            category_processor = {
              target = "foo.severity"
              category = {
                name = "debug"
                filter {
                  query = "@severity: \".\""
                }
              }
              category = {
                name = "verbose"
                filter {
                  query = "@severity: \"-\""
                }
              }
              name       = "sample category processor"
              is_enabled = true
            }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details. "I can see only verbose category" see where? Do get any errors?

Comment: My issue is not getting desired output.. In the output I am getting only last category value not all values under category